# What does "Experiencing authentication issues" in Microsoft Azure imply

Tags: .net, azure, authentication

I always find "Experiencing Authentication issues" notifications in Microsoft Azure.I need to know what these kind of notifications imply.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not take any actions but receive error "Experiencing Authentication issues". I would suggest you contact with azure support to get the detailed reason. Here is [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) that demonstrator us to create a request.